# Dispatch action when createApi query is completed

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I have the following piece of code:

```ts
export const documentApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'documentApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: setBaseUrl('/documents'),
    prepareHeaders: async (headers) => setHeaders(headers),
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getDocuments: builder.query<AssignNormalizedData, TGetDocumentsProps>({
      query: (params) => ({
        url: '',
        params,
      }),
    }),
  }),
});
```

I would like to dispatch an action with the response I get from the server for `getDocuments`.

Can I do it directly in the `createApi` scope?

Comment: It already does dispatch an action with the response - so it's likely that the question is more "how can I access that action?". Where do you want to access that action? In a slice?

Comment: No, I would like to dispatch my own action. I know it dispatches "some action", but IN ADDITION, I'd like to dispatch an additional custom action. Is that possible? I have a reducer that intercepts "NormalizedResponseAction" where normalized responses get handled. I'd like to dispatch that.

Comment: I would really recommend that your reducer instead just reacts to that internal action (if it's a slice, add an extraReducer) - two actions can in some cases mean two rerenders. See the [Redux Style Guide: Avoid Dispatching Many Actions Sequentially](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#avoid-dispatching-many-actions-sequentially)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the endpoint's [`onQueryStarted`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#onquerystarted) function can be used for. Once a query is started you can access the query lifecycle api and `await` the query to be fulfilled and dispatch additional actions.

Example:

```js
export const documentApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'documentApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: setBaseUrl('/documents'),
    prepareHeaders: async (headers) => setHeaders(headers),
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getDocuments: builder.query<AssignNormalizedData, TGetDocumentsProps>({
      query: (params) => ({
        url: '',
        params,
      }),
      onQueryStarted: async (arg, api) => {
        const { dispatch, queryFulfilled } = api;

        const { data } = await queryFulfilled;
        dispatch(someAdditionalAction(data));
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```